# How to run GitLab CI job when UPDATE_REQUIRED is "1"?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to run a subsequent job only when $UPDATE_REQUIRED==1. I have tried rules and only-variables, but I guess I am doing something wrong.

I have the following jobs:

```yaml
update check:
  image: bitnami/git:2.41.0
  stage: check
  script:
    - ./check.sh > build.env
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      dotenv: "build.env"

updates:
  image: internal-image
  stage: build
  dependencies:
    - update check
  script:
    - do something
```

check.sh prints key-value pairs and UPDATE_REQUIRED=1 if there are updates. So my thought was, that I can check with rules or the only syntax if the job should be run like this:

```yaml
updates:
  only:
    variables:
      - $UPDATE_REQUIRED == "1"
updates:
  only:
    variables:
      - $UPDATE_REQUIRED
updates:
  rules:
    - if: $UPDATE_REQUIRED == "1"
      when: always
```

None of them worked, the job was never executed. Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you tried opening the generated artifact to see what's actually in the file? It'll also be good seeing what `script.sh` does to better help you

Comment: Yes, I shortened the script above. `UPDATE_REQUIRED=1` is in the build.env

Comment: @bhito you mean update.sh? Or what do you mean with "script.sh"?

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant `.check.sh`, which is the one generating the env vars

Comment: I can't show the contents due to company restrictions, but the output is this: https://gist.github.com/cwansart/ecf7229cac279ead7ff39aba5dd2fd7e I copy pasted it. I don't think this file is the issue, since I am already using the other variables that are set in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot use these variables as configuration for another CI/CD variable, only on the `scripts` section of a job. Documentation covers this limitation:

> You can create a new environment variables in a job, and pass it to another job in a later stage. **These variables cannot be used as CI/CD variables** to configure a pipeline, but they can be used in job scripts.

Here you have the [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job) to the documentation page that explains it.

Comment: Thank you! I did not find this section so far, but I suspected it is something like that. I'll check the documentation.